# Android delay before the next action

Tags: android, sdk, delay, android-progressbar

in my new Android app I need to push a button to make visibile a progress bar but I need to make it invisible after 3 seconds.

I found this on the web but It does not work:

```
public void search(View view) throws InterruptedException {
ProgressBar progressbarSearch = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Button searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
progressbarSearch.setVisibility(1);
    searchbutton.setText("Searching devices...");

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    //this waits 3 seconds, then will call the run() method below.
    myHandler.postDelayed(stopSearching, 3000);


}

private Runnable stopSearching = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ProgressBar progressbarSearch = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressbarSearch.setVisibility(0);
    }
};
```

Where is the error? The progress bar starts after the button is pressed but it does not become invisible after 3 seconds.

Comment: How about making progressbarSearch a field and reuse it in the Runnable instead of looking it up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
progressbarSearch.setVisibility( View.INVISBLE );
```

You should use a constant here, it's really error prone and not maintainable to use a value. (Proof by example :))

Comment: That's the compiler's job to replace Constants by their values, not a coder's one. Using their name makes your code much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    searchbutton.setText("Searching devices...");
    searchbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ProgressBar progressbarSearch = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            progressbarSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                search(v);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void search(View view) throws InterruptedException {

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    // this waits 3 seconds, then will call the run() method below.
    myHandler.postDelayed(stopSearching, 3000);

}

private Runnable stopSearching = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProgressBar progressbarSearch = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressbarSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
};
```

change your code like this